# Problems with creating a function to reverse a string

Tags: c, function

I need to create a fuction that returns a string. So far I have come up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 256

void str_reverse(char[SIZE], char[SIZE]);

int main(void)
{
    char input[SIZE];
    char output[SIZE];


    printf("Please enter a string\n");
    fgets(input, SIZE, stdin);

    str_reverse(input, output);

    printf("%s \n", output);


    return 0;
}

void str_reverse(char in[SIZE], char out[SIZE])
{

    int i = strlen(in);
    int k = 0;

    for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--)
    {
        out[k] = in[j];
        k++;
    }


}
```

However, whenever I try to run the code, I do not get an output. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
int i = strlen(in);
```

Change it to

```
int i = strlen(in)-1;
```

`strlen()` returns the size of the string, hence when you start copying from `in[]`, `in[j]` would be `\0`. which is getting stored in `out[0]`.

---

Another change you need to do is put a `\0` in the `out[]`, just after the `for` loop

```
for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--)
{
    out[k] = in[j];
    k++;
}
out[k] = '\0';
```

Comment: this worked! thank you for your help :)

Comment: @EllaLautier, You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "reversing" includes the null character too. So the reversed string's first character is `'\0'`. So the string is empty.

Change:

```
for(int j = i ; j>= 0; j--)
```

to

```
for(int j = i - 1; j>= 0; j--)
```

You should also check if the string length is zero before the for loop. Otherwise, `i-1` will become `SIZE_MAX` and you'll have problems with that!

A simple condition such as the following in `str_reverse()` would handle that case:

```
    size_t i = strlen(in);
    int k = 0;

   if (i<=1) return; //empty string or  contains only 1 char char.
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` starts out at `strlen(in), so the first character you copy over to`out`is the null byte at the end of the string.  Every other character then appears after the null terminator, so`out` is an empty string.

Start with `i` at `strlen(in) - 1`, then add the null terminator and the end of the loop:

```
int i = strlen(in) - 1;   // start at the last non-null character
int k = 0;

for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--)
{
    out[k] = in[j];
    k++;
}
out[k] = '\0';    // add the null terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

When `k` is `0` and `j` is `i`, you do the following:

```
out[0] = '\0';
```

Hence, `out` looks like an empty string when the function returns.

Use:

```
for(int j = i-1; j>= 0; j--)
{
    out[k] = in[j];
    k++;
}

out[k] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function variable `i` is set the following way

```
int i = strlen(in);
```

So within the loop

```
for(int j = i; j>= 0; j--)
{
    out[k] = in[j];
    k++;
}
```

then `j` is equal to `i` then `in[j]` is equal to the terminating zero `'\0'` of string `in`. Thus array `out` starts from zero that is it will contain an empty string.

It is better to declare the function itself the following way

```
char * str_reverse( char *out, const char *in );
```

and to return from the function the pointer `out`. In this case you could write for example

```
puts( str_reverse( output, input ) );
```

Take into acount that function `fgets` usually also stores the new line character in the string. You should remove it. you can do it the following way

```
input[strcspn( input, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

Also instead of the type int in this statement

```
int i = strlen(in);
```

it is better to use type `size_t`.

```
size_t i = strlen(in);
```

It is the type of the return value of the function `strlen`. But in this case you should also to write the loop correctly.:)